# Positive real solution to $x^n=x+1$

Tags: asymptotics, roots, inverse, approximation

I am interested in finding the positive real solution to $x^{n}=x+1$, where $n<0, n>1$. For example, if $n = 2$, then $x$ is the golden ratio: $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \approx 1.618$. As $n$ approaches $\infty$, $y$, the solution to the equality, approaches $1$.

To find the solution, I fixed $y$. Then $$y^n=y+1$$ Solving for $n$ yields $$n = \log_{y}(y+1)$$

We now have a solution only in terms of $n$ and $y$. However, I would like to find $y$ as a function of $n$, not the other way around.

If this is not possible, as I suspect, I would like to find an approximation. For my attempt to find an approximation, I examined $$n = \log_{s}(s+1)$$ with $s$ being $1-\frac{1}{y_1}$. I graphed this and got something that asymptotically looked like a line, with a gap from $n = 0$ to $n = 1$, of the form $y_1=kn+1$, where $k \approx -1.4427$. This then means that $$\frac{1}{1-y}=kn+1 \rightarrow y \approx -\frac{1}{kn+1}+1$$ . This matches up with [the graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qykzelln3m). In the graph, $n$ is on the $x$-axis.

My questions:

Is there a closed form for the inverse of $n = \log_y(y+1)$?

What is the exact value of $k$?

What is a better approximation, perhaps of the form $y=c_0+\frac{1}{c_1n+d_1}+ \frac{1}{c_2n^2+d_2} +...$?

**Edit:**

Letting $$t = 1-\frac{1}{y_1-1+\frac{1}{kn+1}}$$ I graphed $n=\log_t(t+1)$ This was asymptotically equal to $$y_1=kn+2$$
However, I'm not sure how to use this in order to get a better estimate.

**Edit 2:**

I appreciate the answers so far. However, using a simple sum of inverse powers will not work near $x = 0$. At $x = 0$, the approximations of the form $y=a_0+a_1x^{-1}+a_2x^{-2}+...$ will diverge to $-\infty$. In fact, successive approximations get worse for $-1<x<0$. On the other hand, $$y = -\frac{1}{kn+1}+1$$ approaches $0$ as $n$ approaches $0$.

Comment: Your $k$ matches numerically the value of $-\frac{1}{\ln 2}$.

Comment: That seems accurate, but why is that?

Comment: It does sort of make sense that for large $n$, the solution should be close to 1, then $x+1 \approx 2$ should imply $x$ close to $2^{1/n} \sim 1 + \frac{1}{n} \ln 2$.  It wouldn't be at all surprising to see a bootstrapping argument making this sort of reasoning precise.  (And then from there, you would be able to come up with more asymptotic terms, probably of the form $x_n - 1 - \frac{1}{n} \ln 2 \sim \frac{c_2}{n^2}$, $x_n - 1 - \frac{1}{n} \ln 2 - \frac{c_2}{n^2} \sim \frac{c_3}{n^3}$, etc.)

Comment: It just struck me that it might be easier to do asymptotic analysis with the equivalent $x_n = (1 + x_n)^{1/n}$ so that in the right hand side both $x_n - 1$ and $1/n$ are small numbers.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Can you explain how to do this? What are you saying the $x_n$ are? I'm not sure I follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the equivalent equation $x = (x+1)^{1/n}$; then, since we are interested in the behavior as $n \to \pm\infty$ (and since $\frac{1}{n}$ already appears in the equation), let us set $\epsilon := \frac{1}{n}$.

Now, consider the function $F(\epsilon, x) := x - (x+1)^\epsilon$.  We have that $F$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $(0, 1)$; $F(0, 1) = 0$; and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(0, 1) = 1 \ne 0$.  Therefore, by the Implicit Function Theorem, there is a differentiable function $f(\epsilon)$ on a neighborhood of $\epsilon = 0$ such that $f(0) = 1$ and $F(\epsilon, f(\epsilon)) = 0$.  This function $f(\epsilon)$ is exactly the solution to the equation that we were looking for as a function of $\epsilon$.

Furtherfore, $f'(0) = -\frac{\partial F/\partial \epsilon(0, 1)}{\partial F/\partial x(0, 1)} = \ln 2$.  It follows that $f(\epsilon) = 1 + \epsilon \ln 2 + o(\epsilon) = 1 + \frac{\ln 2}{n} + o(\frac{1}{n})$.

If we want to get more accurate approximations, then observe that since $F$ is $C^\infty$ near $(0, 1)$, then $f \in C^\infty$ in a neighborhood of 0 also, so Taylor series approximations will give the desired refinements.  The higher derivatives of $f$ at 0, in turn, can be found by a standard implicit differentiation of the equation $f(\epsilon) - (f(\epsilon) + 1)^\epsilon = 0$.

Comment: Same result as mine, and simpler. Nice.

Comment: Thanks for this! Just to make sure I understand correctly, letting $g = \ln(2)$, is $$y=1+gn^{-1}+(\frac{1}{2}(g+g^2))n^{-2}+\frac{1}{24}(6g+15g^2+4g^3)n^{-3}$$ the best approximation going up to an $n^{-3}$ term? Also is the coefficient of the $n^{-5}$ term $\frac{1}{960}(60g+420g^2+510g^3+135g^4+8g^5)$?

Comment: Those are the coefficients I got, though by a slightly different method - in `maxima` I used `taylor((1+log(2)*eps)^eps,eps,0,5);` then `taylor((1+%o1)^eps,eps,0,5);` then with `%o2` etc. until it stabilized.  (Iterating the function $x \mapsto (1+x)^{1/n}$ a few times starting at $x=1$ would also be a nice simple way to find a numerical solution.)

Comment: With that method, the $n^{-4}$ coefficient is $\frac{1}{48}(6g+27g^2+18g^3+2g^4)$.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a closed form, but for a slightly better approximation, including Daniel Schepler's $\ln(2) \approx 0.6931471806 \approx \frac{1}{1.4427}$, you might try something like $$y \approx 1+\log_e(2) n^{-1}+0.5868n^{-2}+ 0.529 n^{-3}+ 0.49 n^{-4}$$ giving the following values - not brilliant for small $n$ as you would benefit from more terms and more precise coefficients but not bad for larger $n$

```
    n    y suggested     y^n              y^n - (1+y)
    2   1.5900235903    2.5281750176    -0.0618485726
    3   1.3218910355    2.3098669885    -0.0120240470
    4   1.2201414826    2.2163623827    -0.0037791000
    5   1.1671174361    2.1655727910    -0.0015446451
    6   1.1346516906    2.1339065049    -0.0007451857
    7   1.1127428917    2.1123398903    -0.0004030014
    8   1.0969649796    2.0967280452    -0.0002369344
    9   1.0850611332    2.0849126584    -0.0001484747
   10   1.0757607181    2.0756628744    -0.0000978437
   20   1.0361935465    2.0361870122    -0.0000065343
   50   1.0141019740    2.0141017411    -0.0000002330
  100   1.0069906857    2.0069906570    -0.0000000287
  200   1.0034804723    2.0034804668    -0.0000000056
  500   1.0013886458    2.0013886448    -0.0000000010
 1000   1.0006937345    2.0006937342    -0.0000000003
 2000   1.0003467204    2.0003467202    -0.0000000001
 5000   1.0001386529    2.0001386529    -0.0000000000
10000   1.0000693206    2.0000693206    -0.0000000000
```

Comment: I think when I did an expanded computation of the exact coefficients for higher terms, the $n^{-2}$ coefficient ended up being $\frac{1}{2} ((\ln 2)^2 + \ln 2)$ which is indeed pretty close to 0.5868.

Comment: The numerical values of the exact coefficients, to four decimal places: $1 + 0.6931n^{-1} + 0.5868n^{-2} + 0.5291n^{-3} + 0.4914n^{-4} + 0.4642n^{-5} + O(n^{-6})$.

Answer (score 0):

The root is,
for large $n$,
$1+\frac{\ln(2)}{n}+O(\frac1{n^2})
$.

Let
$f(x) = x^n-x-1$.
$f(0) = -1,
f(1) = -1,
f(2) = 2^n-3
\gt 0$
for
$n \ge 2$.

$f'(x)
=nx^{n-1} -1
\ge n-1$
for $x \ge 1$.
Therefore
only one real root
with $x > 1$.
Let
$x_0$ be that root.

Since
$(1+\frac1{n})^{n+1}
\gt e$,
$f(1+\frac1{n-1})
=(1+\frac1{n-1})^n-(1+\frac1{n-1})-1
\gt e-2-\frac1{n-1}
\gt 0$
for $n-1 \gt \frac1{.7}$
or $n \ge 3$.

Therefore
$1 \lt x_0
\lt 1+\frac1{n-1}
$.

Let's look for a root
of the form
$1+\frac{c}{n}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
f(1+\dfrac{c}{n})
&=(1+\dfrac{c}{n})^n-(1+\dfrac{c}{n})-1\\
&=e^{n\ln(1+c/n)}-2-\dfrac{c}{n}\\
&=e^{n(c/n-c^2/(2n^2)+O(1/n^3)))}-2-\dfrac{c}{n}\\
&=e^{c-c^2/(2n)+O(1/n^2)}-2-\dfrac{c}{n}\\
&=e^{c}e^{-c^2/(2n)+O(1/n^2)}-2-\dfrac{c}{n}\\
&=e^{c}(1-c^2/(2n)+O(1/n^2))-2-\dfrac{c}{n}\\
&=e^{c}-e^{c}(c^2/(2n)+O(1/n^2))-2-\dfrac{c}{n}\\
&=e^{c}-2-\frac{c}{n}(1+\frac{ce^{c}}{2})+O(1/n^2)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $e^{c} = 2$,
or
$c = \ln(2)
$,
$f(1+\dfrac{c}{n})
=-\frac{\ln(2)}{n}(1+\ln(2))+O(\frac1{n^2})
$
and,
for any other $c$,
$f(1+\dfrac{c}{n})
=e^c-2 +O(\frac1{n})
$.

Comment: I know you want a general solution but, for $n=2$, we have, from the quadratic equation $\phi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}=1.61803398874....$

Comment: I was concerned with large $n$.

Answer (score 0):

*Another possible way to get an approximation.*

Let us build a $[1,k]$ Padé approximant of $x^n-x-1$ around $x=1$ which would write
$$x^n-x-1\sim\frac {a_0^{(k)}+a_1^{(k)}(x-1)} {1+\sum_{p=1}^k b_p^{(k)}(x-1)^k}$$ and the approximate solution would be
$$x_{(k)}=1-\frac{a_0^{(k) }} {a_1^{(k) } }$$ Using for example $k=6$, this would give
$$x_{(6)}=1+\frac{32781 n^5-133728 n^4+209727 n^3-154728 n^2+51156 n-5040 } {47293 n^6-232966 n^5+463695 n^4-471470 n^3+252512 n^2-64224 n+5040 }$$ which, expanded as a series for infinitely large values of $n$ would give
$$x_{(6)}=1+\frac{32781}{47293 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ and $\frac{32781}{47293}=0.693147$ which is, for six significant figures, $\log(2)$.

Building the same table as in Henry's answer
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 2 & 1.61904761905 &  1.61803398875 \\
 3 & 1.32472324723 &  1.32471795727 \\
 4 & 1.22074383382 &  1.22074408461 \\
 5 & 1.16730393752 &  1.16730397826 \\
 6 & 1.13472418394 &  1.13472413840 \\
 7 & 1.11277574322 &  1.11277568428 \\
 8 & 1.09698161049 &  1.09698155780 \\
 9 & 1.08507028837 &  1.08507024549 \\
 10 & 1.07576609989 &  1.07576606609 \\
 20 & 1.03619371886 &  1.03619371713 \\
 50 & 1.01410197382 &  1.01410197638 \\
 100 & 1.00699068416 &  1.00699068585 \\
 200 & 1.00348047141 &  1.00348047235 \\
 500 & 1.00138864541 &  1.00138864580 \\
 1000 & 1.00069373431 &  1.00069373451 \\
 2000 & 1.00034672026 &  1.00034672036 \\
 5000 & 1.00013865287 &  1.00013865291 \\
 10000 & 1.00006932057 &  1.00006932057
\end{array}
\right)$$